# How can I set up a PayPal Live App ID for an iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, paypal, payment-processing, paypal-subscriptions

I am working on an application that allows user to buy products online. In this app I have integrated PayPal presently with sandbox APP Id. But the problem is when we are on simulator it works great but when we install app on the device it doesn't work. Through some research I found that we will need LIVE APP ID to integrate PayPal on device and for this I need to submit app to PayPal developer site.

Does anybody knows about the procedure to submit app to PayPal developer site for live app id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/going-live-with-your-application

Posting it since some of the links above were dead.

Answer (score 5):

This has been easy, I have just submitted an iPhone app to go live.

First go to www.x.com, it asks you to sign in giving your paypal  credentials. Once you are in , go to My Account at the top of the screen , and then press New App , fill in the form and there you go.

If your app does not do anything especial your app could be easily approved, even automatically like mine.

I hope it helps.

Anyway the instructions can be found at www.paypal.com ( iOS guidance file )

Answer (score 1):

open developer.paypal.com site and register first.

but you not get directly Live paypal id fist submit your application on app store after you use live app id.